# UrlFetchApp Method does not work and gives 405 error in retrieving data from an API?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, urlfetch, http-status-code-405, clockify

I am trying to get the Clockify detailed time report into Google Sheets. When I try to use the URL fetch method, it gives me an error:

`Exception: Request failed for https://reports.api.clockify.me returned code 405. Truncated server response: {"code":405, "message": "HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)`

Here is the documentation - https://docs.clockify.me/#tag/Time-Entry-Report/operation/generateDetailedReport

I am using this code:

```
function getTimeReport() {
  
  var body = {"dateRangeStart":"2023-10-05T00:00:00.000Z","dateRangeEnd":"2023-05-05T23:59:59.000Z","detailedFilter":{"page":1,"pageSize":1000,"options":{"totals":"EXCLUDE"}}}
  
  var headers = {
    "headers": {
      "x-Api-Key": "XXX",
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "Application": "Custom",
      "muteHttpExceptions": "true",
      "Method": "POST",
      "payload": body
    }
  };
  
  var workspaceId = "XXX";
  
  var url = `https://reports.api.clockify.me/v1/workspaces/${workspaceId}/reports/detailed`;
  Logger.log(url);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers);
  Logger.log(response);
```

I double-checked the workspace ID and API key both are correct. May I know where I am going wrong?

Comment: if I understood it correctly, as per the documentation you have shared, you are using an API using a `POST` method. It can't be used to retrieve data since POST methods are used to send data to the server. If you are able to get data using the URL you must be able to access it when copying it in the browser. Can you double check what is being returned when you access it through the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, when the values of `body` and the value of `x-Api-Key` are valid values, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function getTimeReport() {
  var body = { "dateRangeStart": "2023-10-05T00:00:00.000Z", "dateRangeEnd": "2023-05-05T23:59:59.000Z", "detailedFilter": { "page": 1, "pageSize": 1000, "options": { "totals": "EXCLUDE" } } };

  var options = {
    "headers": { "x-Api-Key": "XXX" },
    "muteHttpExceptions": "true",
    "Method": "POST",
    "payload": JSON.stringify(body),
    "contentType": "application/json",
  };

  var workspaceId = "XXX";

  var url = `https://reports.api.clockify.me/v1/workspaces/${workspaceId}/reports/detailed`;
  Logger.log(url);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

- I thought that the request of this modified script is the same as the specification of the API of your provided URL.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It gives this error ``` {"code":501,"message":"Invalid date range. dateRangeStart must be before dateRangeEnd."}```

Comment: Apologies. I made a mistake with the dates. It's fixed now. Thanks for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Arif Ahmed Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.